# How to add year and month in count down Timer Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer, nstimeinterval

Right now I have added seconds and min. in my timer. Additionally I need to add Hours month and year in my timer like below image:

[image]

Here is the code which I have implemented :

```
    // CountDown Timer
In My view DidLoad I have initialized my variables:
currHour = 1;
currMinute= 3;
currSeconds= 00;

-(void)start {
    timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
-(void)timerFired {
    if((currHour>0 || currHour>=0) && (currMinute>0 || currSeconds>=0) && currMinute>=0) {

        if(currSeconds==0) {
            currMinute-=1;
            currSeconds=59;
        }
        else if(currSeconds>0) {
            currSeconds-=1;
        }
        if(currMinute>-1)
            [self.progress setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%@%02d %@",currMinute,@":",currSeconds,@"Sec"]];
    }
    else {
        self.countDownView.hidden = TRUE;
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

It's working till Minutes and seconds.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [NSDateComponentsFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatecomponentsformatter). It is able to do your entire time math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to viewDidLoad next code  and save target date as property or ivar

```
NSTimeInterval currentDateSeconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
NSTimeInterval targetDateSeconds = currentDateSeconds + [self secondsInDay:0 hour:1 min:3 sec:0];
targetDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:targetDateSeconds];
```

then add method for convert target date to seconds, e.g. in your example is 1 hour 3 min

```
- (NSTimeInterval) secondsInDay: (int) day hour:(int)hour min:(int)min sec: (int)sec {
NSTimeInterval secondsInOneDay = 24 * 60 * 60;
return day * secondsInOneDay + hour * 60 * 60 + min * 60 + sec; }
```

then use next `timeFired` method:

```
-(void)timerFired {
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:[NSDate date] toDate:targetDate options:0];

NSInteger year = dateComponents.year;
NSInteger month = dateComponents.month;
NSInteger day = dateComponents.day;
NSInteger minute = dateComponents.minute;
NSInteger second = dateComponents.second;

if(year == 0 &&
    month == 0 &&
    day == 0 &&
    minute == 0 &&
   second == 0) {
    NSLog(@"FINISH");
    [timer invalidate];
} else {
    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%@%02d %@",minute,@":",second,@"Sec"]);
}}
```

Comment: So the output will be same as I want? Because I have timestamp

Comment: yep, `timerFired` calculates remaining date components

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` we get date when timer finishes work via converting `currHour, currMinute, currSeconds` to seconds and add then to current date. Then in `timerFired` we get current date and calculate how much time remains.

Comment: I tried with `NSString *interval = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"event_start_date_time_in_ms"];
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [interval doubleValue];
    NSTimeInterval currentDateSeconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSTimeInterval targetDateSeconds = currentDateSeconds + timeInterval;;
    targetDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:targetDateSeconds];` But I get wrong details in timer

Comment: yes, because `event_start_date_time_in_ms` has  the same value each run time, so your gap between `currentDateSeconds` and `targetDateSeconds` is always the same. I can advice you once calculate and save `targetDateSeconds` to `userdefaults`,and then each run time create `targetDate` from that saved value.

Comment: I am doing the same. that interval I stored in another class. I am just fetching that value in viewDidLoad. above commented code I have implemented in ViewDidLoad only.

Comment: if you store right time interval in another class, you need just get date from that interval. `NSString *interval = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"event_start_date_time_in_ms"];
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [interval doubleValue];
    targetDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970: timeInterval];`

Comment: still it's wrong. Here is my timestamp : 1551333600000 but it comes as 8 days 11 hours 58 min and .. sec

Comment: probably you wrong calculate this timestamp and how many days/hours/mins you'd like to see

Comment: I got the issue. actually in response I get timestamp in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `NSTimer` method with a block you don't need to store any time variables (or timer for that matter), which is kind of neat:

```
- (void)startCountdownWithNumberOfSeconds:(NSTimeInterval)seconds {

    __block NSTimeInterval remainingTime = seconds;
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 repeats:YES block:^(NSTimer *timer) {

        NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond)
                                                   fromDate:[NSDate date]
                                                     toDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:remainingTime--]
                                                    options:kNilOptions];
        NSLog(@"Remaining time: %@", components.description);

        if (remainingTime > 0) {
            self.progress.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d", (int)components.day, (int)components.hour, (int)components.minute, (int)components.second];
        }
        else {
            [timer invalidate];
        }
    }];
}
```

`NSCalendar` has a lot of unit options, like `NSCalendarUnitYear` and `NSCalendarUnitMonth` so you can just add them to the list when you need them.